# Python tem alguma forma de pingar um IP nativamente?

Tags: python

Existe alguma forma de pingar um IP nativamente no python, ou uma library?

Por exemplo, eu faço assim:

```
import os
ips = ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3"] 
cmd = "ping -n 3 "
for ip in ips:
    print(os.popen(cmd + ip).readlines())
```

Tem alguma outra forma sem ser usando comando (`ping -n 3 192.168...`) da própria plataforma (linux, windows, macOs...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há o [Pyping](https://github.com/certator/pyping) que você pode usar, e qualquer outra forma de usar o ping é acionando ele pelo próprio sistema diferente desta.

Use o pip para instalar:

```
pip install pyping
```

Veja um exemplo:

```
import pyping

r = pyping.ping('192.168.0.1')
print(r.ret_code)
```

## Importante

Caso for usar o Pyping certifique-se de executar o script como 'Administrador' se for no Windows.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado.

Só uma observação, eu conseguir usar ele apenas no python2.7, que para mim já está ótimo. Não funcionou no python3.7.

No 3.7 da essa mensagem:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'